# Uncertainty in Enumerated Data

Tags: regression, simulation, uncertainty

I am interested in assessing possible uncertainty in enumerated data.

To do this, I randomly pick 80% of the enumerated data to predict the remaining 20% through a regression analysis. I reapeat the process 1000 times. Ideally, this should allow me to assess uncertainty affecting explanatory and predictive performances in a regression context.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems that what you are describing is simply a cross validation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "enumerated" data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is called [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29). It is a part of broader family of [resampling methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104040/resampling-simulation-methods-monte-carlo-bootstrapping-jackknifing-cross). In such methods you repeat resampling procedure multiple times:

- In [**permutation test**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/bootstrapping-vs-permutation-tests) you sample without replacement $N$ values out of sample consisting of $N$ cases (i.e. randomly shuffle the cases) and then compute some statistic $S$ on such sample. This enables you to generate null distribution of $S$ so to compute probability of observing such (or more extreme) value of $S$ as you obtained on your original sample.
- In [**bootstrap**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26088/explaining-to-laypeople-why-bootstrapping-works) you sample with replacement $N$ values out or your original sample. This lets you to re-create by simulation distribution of your sample and asses uncertainty of your estimate.
- In [**cross-validation**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/cross-validation-in-plain-english) you randomly pick some proportion $p$ of $N$ cases, so to use $p \times N$ cases for training your model and $(1-p) \times N$ cases for prediction. By this you can learn about uncertainty of your predictions.

Notice that those are general descriptions of most common methods, while in reality there is a greater variety of such methods and in practice the procedures can be and often are more complicated than the simplified descriptions.